# How to LOCATE() work for a full word not for string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to fetch results which has particular keywords for example 'php', 'htm'. I also want to fetch how many keywords are exists in a row.

For example I have two rows.
One row has skill field with vlue :- 'php,html, asp,testing'
And other has :- 'html,asp,testing'

Now if I search for keyword 'php' and 'htm' then it may return one record and I also want to know that which keyword is exist in the row. Such as if row has only one keyword then it may 50% matching and if row has both keywords in records then it may 100% matching.

I am using below sql query :-

```
  SELECT ROUND(((if(LOCATE("php",skill)>0,25,0) + if(LOCATE("htm",skill)>0,25,0)) * 100) / 50) AS Candidate__SkillTot,
       `Candidate`.`id`
FROM `kings_desktop`.`candidates` AS `Candidate`
LEFT JOIN `kings_desktop`.`cand_accounts` AS `CandAccount` ON (`CandAccount`.`candidate_id` = `Candidate`.`id`)
WHERE (if(LOCATE("php",skill)>0,25,0) + if(LOCATE("htm",skill)>0,25,0)) LIMIT 100
```

The problem is that this query is returning both records. And I want only first row with 50% of `Candidate__SkillTot` value

Comment: It's almost never a good idea to violate the [first normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). If you can't change it, you should take a look at [FIND_IN_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).